# Change profile custom field type (Sitefinity 6.3)

Tags: sitefinity

I have an old installation of Sitefinity (version 6.3)
On the profile, I have a custom field that is numeric. I now have the needs to change this to hold a string instead.

What I found was that there is no easy way to change datatype (https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/edit-an-existing-custom-field), but is It possible by code/config?

I'm guessing that one option is to delete the field, and then recreate it is a possibility, but since I have much data it would be a lot of work to restore data in the field. Is this the only way?

Edit: I've deleted the column and recreated it as a string/varchar. 
I'm now facing a problem with some type of converter

```
type converter initialization failed. The converter with name 'DecimalConverter' does not convert from CLR type 'System. String' to SQL type 'DECIMAL'.
Parameter name: converterName
Actual value was OpenAccessRuntime.Data.DecimalConverter, Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime, Version=2013.3.1211.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342.
```

This line in stack trace is of importance

```
[MetadataException: The metadata for field 'CustomerNo_sv' of class 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Model.SitefinityProfile' cannot be initialized: Type converter initialization failed. The converter with name 'DecimalConverter' does not convert from CLR type 'System. String' to SQL type 'DECIMAL'.
Parameter name: converterName
Actual value was OpenAccessRuntime.Data.DecimalConverter, Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime, Version=2013.3.1211.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342.]
```

Somehow the language specified values isn't converted as I can see. Now the whole site is down and I can't reach backend. So I guess I have to solve this out in DB?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in similar cases is this:

I create the new field and then populate the new column in the database with the values from the old column (field).

In your case, you'd be looking at the **sf_sitefinity_profile** table.

This way the data will be migrated to the new field.

After that you can delete the old field and start using the new one.

Comment: The only problem I see is that I have to change the propertyname everywhare in the code. If I instead do a temp table, copy the value, delete field and then cast and repopulate, I can use the same name. Less change in code, more stuff just one time.

edit: I do need to change the datatype to string from int as well in code, so maybe not that much diff.

Comment: Then in addition to the above steps - after deleting the old field - create a new field with the name of the old field and the proper type and save. Then do again data migration to it. So the workflow would be:
old field (int): Height
new field (string): HeightTemp
copy data from Height to HeightTemp
Delete Height
Create Height (string)
copy data from HeightTemp to Height
Delete HeightTemp

Comment: Hm, did you deleted the old field and created the new one in one go? That would explain the error.
You should have deleted the old one, save changes, then create a new one (because they have the same name)

Comment: I did save and then restored. The error seems to be related that I created a localization property by mistake (_sv in the end is swedish language). I restored a backup and created a new field (not localized), changed all the calls for the field to the new name, and now it's working.